# Optimal way to generate an image in PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to auto generate a image to use for the facebook preview when using the facebook share button.

The image to be shared is basically a combination of the user's profile picture and some custom artwork.

Currently, I am just displaying it on my website in html/css but in order for me to share it I have to generate it into a single image.

I get a lot of traffic and I was wondering what the most optimal way to do this would be in order to not over load the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your setup. However if your are running a setup as

Server : php + database

Client : html + css + JS

then the answer to your question is pretty clear :
if you want to protect your server from an overload, do it on the client side, that is to say with JavaScript!